# Is it correct to say "information furnished above"?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

I have just received a CV from India, where it is stated at the end

> I hereby declare that information **furnished** above is true to the best of my knowledge

(emphasis mine)

It sounds terrible to me and I was quite sure it is incorrect way to say 'provided', 'given', 'specified' etc. But after checking on internet, I have found

http://www.yourdictionary.com/furnish

> 2. to supply; provide; give: to furnish information

It still doesn't mean that 'furnished information' is a right thing to say, but it got me wondering. Is this phrase common outside of India? Does it sound right to native speaker?

Comment: It would definitely read to me like someone who didn't write English as a first language, as I'd usually expect either "the above information" or at the least, "provided".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it "correct" to say it? - Well your research has already provided the answer to that - Yes.

Is it common outside of India? - Only when speakers of Indian English are speaking/writing outside of India. I'm a native of Britain, and have never been to India, but guessed the speaker was Indian from the title of your question alone, before I read the full context.

Does it sound right to a native speaker? - No. It sounds like Indian English, not "normal" English. I can easily understand it though.

Answer (score 1):

As a Brit, I would say that it might make sense by definition, but isn't at all something that would be said by a native speaker.
This side of the Atlantic at least '*Furnished*' is not considered a synonym for '*Supplied*' or '*Given*'

See the Cambridge English Dictionary entry here:
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/furnish

Note that only Americans, and English speakers taught in the American fashion, would use such a phrase.

Perhaps a more fitting sentence would have been:

> I hereby declare that, to the best of my knowledge, the information given in the above text is true.

Comment: Your definition link says "Definition of “furnish” from the Cambridge Advanced Learner’s Dictionary & Thesaurus", which unsurprisingly doesn't contain all definitions. [Dictionary.reference.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/furnish?s=t), if you scroll down to "British Dictionary definitions" from Collins, *does* include the quoted usage: "to give; supply: *the records furnished the information required*". Note that Indian English is based on Victorian British English, not American English.

Comment: Dictionary.reference is not a site that I have perticular confidence in @AndyT, I usually chose to stick with the highly respected and world-renowned dictionaries of English origin; Collins, Oxford and Cambridge.

And yes I am in fact aware that India was part of our Empire.. and that is where they get their English.

Comment: And what about Collins? You can follow [this link](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/furnish) if you want, which unsurprisingly has exactly the same wording as that quoted by dictionary.reference.com.

Comment: In my experience I have never encountered the use of the word in that context and thus had no reason to suspect that the Cambridge dictionary was incorrect or missing definitions.